# Print available methods of a component in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, flash-cs4

I have a custom made button in as3, and I would like to print all the methods available for it. How can I do it?

Comment: At run time, or before comile time?

Comment: at runtime please, maybe only to print the methods when I do the CRTL+ENTER

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Apart from not being useful in any real-world application, it would also make your methods viewable to everyone who plays the movie... :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build-in function `describeType` to accomplish this. Just pass in a type and it will return an XML-object containing not only the methods, but also variables, accessors and more. See [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for is:

```
for(var prop:String in obj) {
   if(obj[prop] is Function) trace(prop);
}
```

Comment: This will only work for dynamic objects, not for instances of custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var f:Function in yourObject) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Try that

Comment: I tried `for (var f:Function in btn) {
      trace(f);
 }` but got error  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Function.

Comment: That's because there is no implicit conversion for Function to String. Try `trace(f.toString());`

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, but now get `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method toString through a reference with static type Function.`

Comment: Try `f.Call()` to see if that's the problem

Comment: Again, for...in only works for dynamic objects. If it is an instance of a custom class, `describeType` is the right way to go.